# Loop through an object to print specific properties?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of unique elements, uniqueID, that match up with the "ID" property of an object an the contentBlock array. My code so far loops through the uniqueID and contentBlock arrays and finds when the element value in uniqueID is equal to the ID value in the contentBlock.

I want to now return the properties title, age, and state (NOT ID) of an object if the uniqueID is equal to the ID value, but unsure how to print these multiple properties in my forEach loops below, could someone guide me on this?

```
var uniqueID = ["a", "c"];

var contentBlock = [
  {
    title: "John",
    age: 24,
    state: "NY",
    ID: "a"
}, 
{
    title: "Jane",
    age: 27,
    state: "CA",
    ID: "b"
}, 
{
    title: "Joe",
    age: 32,
    state: "NY",
    ID: "c"
}, 
{
    title: "Carl",
    age: 43,
    state: "MI",
    ID: "d"
} 
]


uniqueID.forEach(function (item) {
  contentBlock.forEach(function(tile) {
    if (item === tile.ID) {
//return these properties of each object identified as unique
        console.log(tile.title);
        console.log(tile.age)
        console.log(tile.state)
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Array#filter` instead.

```js
var contentBlock = [{title:"John",age:24,state:"NY",ID:"a"},{title:"Jane",age:27,state:"CA",ID:"b"},{title:"Joe",age:32,state:"NY",ID:"c"},{title:"Carl",age:43,state:"MI",ID:"d"}], uniqueID = ["a", "c"],
    hash = contentBlock.filter(v => uniqueID.indexOf(v.ID) > -1),
    res = hash.map(v => Object.assign({}, {title: v.title, age: v.age, state: v.state}));
    
    console.log(res);
```

Comment: Is there an alternative way to write this using _.filter from underscore.js? I'm new to tempting JS so I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Tyler Underscore filter works pretty similar, but what's the point. Keep using pure js.